# How can I check if a number is both an Armstrong or a palindrome in simple techniques

Tags: c

So I am writing a code to check if a number is a palindrome or an Armstrong or both. Mind yo I'm just a high schooler so I need to do it in basic techniques as I haven't learnt anything else than these techniques yet and also because I can't use more than taught.
Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a,b,c=0,d,e=0,a1,org;
    printf("Please enter your three digit number: ");
    scanf("%d",&org);
    org=a1;
    org=a;
    while(a!=0){
        b=a%10;
        c=c*10+b;
        a=a/10;
    }
    while(a1!=0){
        d=a1%10;
        e=e+d*d*d;
        a1=a1/10;
    }
    
    if(c==org && e==org){
        printf("The entered number is both a palindrome and a armstrong");
    }
    else if(e==org && c!=org){
        printf("The entered number is an armstrong");
    }
    else if(c==org && e!=org){
        printf("The entered number is a palindrome");
    }
    else{
        printf("The entered number is not a palindrome or an armstrong");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

I wrote the code but it just gave the same output for any integer value I entered.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&org); org=a1; org=a;` doesn't make sense. You read an integer and then immediately assign two different uninitialized variables to it discarding the read value. Would `a1 = org;` and `a = org;` make more sense?

Comment: You might consider using more descriptive variable names. The one character names make it harder to read and understand your code which also makes it harder to write and debug. Best to learn good habits when you're starting than have to unlearn them later when you're more experienced.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your code, and when I compiled the program, I received a compiler warning about not using the output of the "scanf" operation, which you might want to review, plus two warnings about using uninitialized variables.

```
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Check/main.c|7|warning: ‘a1’ is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]|
/home/craig/C_Programs/Console/Check/main.c|8|warning: ‘a’ is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]|
```

These point to issues as noted in the good comments above that will lead to undefined behavior where those variables are used.

Testing out the compiled program utilizing a known three-digit number that is an Armstrong number netted the following incorrect statement.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Check/bin/Release$ ./Check 
Please enter your three digit number: 371
The entered number is both a palindrome and a armstrong
```

The entered number definitely is not a palindrome, but is stated as such, most likely from the undefined behavior.

In my analysis of testing for palindromes over the years, I have found that it is actually easier to treat a group of digits, and/or characters as a string when performing a check for a palindrome.  With that in mind, following is a refactored version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int arm, test;
    char num[4];

    printf("Please enter your three digit number: ");
    scanf("%s", num);

    test = atoi(num);   /* Converts the entered string of digits to an integer  */

    /* FYI, since the entered number is only three digits, the number will be a palindrome if the first digit is equal to the third digit   */

    arm = (num[0] - '0') * (num[0] - '0') * (num[0] - '0') + (num[1] - '0') * (num[1] - '0')* (num[1] - '0') + (num[2] - '0') * (num[2] - '0') * (num[2] - '0');

    if ((arm == test) && (num[0] == num[2]))
        printf("%s is both an Armstrong number and a palindrome\n", num);
    else if (arm == test)
        printf("%s is an Armstrong number but not a palindrome\n", num);
    else if (num[0] == num[2])
        printf("%s is a palindrome but not an Armstrong number\n", num);
    else
        printf("%s is neither an Armstrong number or palindrome\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Following are some key points.

- The three digit number to be entered is entered as a string value, and then stored into an integer variable.
- Each digit character is converted into its integer value by subtracting the ASCII value of '0' from the character's ASCII value and then utilized in a somewhat lengthy but straightforward formula to calculate the Armstrong test value.
- Since the entered value is just three digits, if the first digit (num[0]) is equal to the third digit (num[2]), then the entered value is a palindrome, which makes the testing for a palindrome simpler.

With that, following tests were run in the terminal and assumes that the user may enter a value with leading zeros.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Check/bin/Release$ ./Check 
Please enter your three digit number: 456
456 is neither an Armstrong number or palindrome
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Check/bin/Release$ ./Check 
Please enter your three digit number: 232
232 is a palindrome but not an Armstrong number
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Check/bin/Release$ ./Check 
Please enter your three digit number: 371
371 is an Armstrong number but not a palindrome
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Check/bin/Release$ ./Check 
Please enter your three digit number: 000
000 is both an Armstrong number and a palindrome
```

The takeaway from this is be cognizant of any warnings that may be listed when compiling your code as they may be indicators of possible undefined behavior.  Also, you may want to delve some more into some "C" tutorial literature especially as it pertains to character arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research and found out that most of the numbers that are both palindrome and armstrong are not known to us yet.

However, here is a simple implementation for the question you asked for. It's the easiest approach anyone can think of.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int rem,n,i,rev,arm,org;
    puts("Enter a number");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    arm = 0;
    org = n;//setting original number
    while(n!=0){
        rem = n %10;
        arm = arm + rem*rem*rem; //formula for armstrong number
        rev = rev*10+rem; //palindrome reversing
        n=n/10;
    }
    if (rev == org && arm == org){
        puts("The number is both an armstrong and palindrome");
    }
    else if(rev == org){
        puts("The number is palindrome but not armstrong");
    }
    else if(arm == org){
        puts("The number is an armstrong but not palindrome");
    }
    else{
        puts("The number is not both an armstrong and palindrome");
    }
}
```

Outputs:

Test case 1:

```
Enter a number
999
The number is palindrome but not armstrong
```

Test case 2:

```
Enter a number
153
The number is an armstrong but not palindrome
```

Test case 3:

```
Enter a number
122
The number is not both an armstrong and palindrome
```

This code considers all the 4 possible cases. However, keep in mind that not many numbers that are both palindrome and armstrong are known to us so the use case is quite limited or non existent.

Comment: `rev` appears to be uninitialized making `rev = rev*10+rem;` rather unpredictable.